# Why Graph API not providing AAD users last activity correctly

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Graph api to fetch AAD users list

```
        internal static async Task<List<Users>> GetUsers()
        {
            List<Users> uList = new List<Users>();
            try
            {
                IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
               .Create(AppId)
               .WithTenantId(TenantId)
               .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
               .Build();

                ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
                graphClient.BaseUrl = Constant.BaseUrl;

                var result = await graphClient.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Select("Id,Mail,signInActivity")
                    .GetAsync();
                while (true)
                {
                    foreach (var item in result.CurrentPage)
                    {
                        var user = new Users
                        {
                            Id = item.Id,
                            EmailId = item.Mail,                            
                            AdditionalData = item.AdditionalData,
                            User = item
                        };
                        var lastActivityDictonery = item.AdditionalData;
                        var arr = ToStringArray(lastActivityDictonery["signInActivity"]);

                        var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(arr[0]);
                        var lastSignInDateTime = Convert.ToString(parsedJson["lastSignInDateTime"]);
                        var lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime = Convert.ToString(parsedJson["lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime"]);
                        user.LastLoginDate = lastSignInDateTime;
                        user.lastNonInteractiveLogInDate = lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime;
                        
                        uList.Add(user);
                    }

                    if (result.NextPageRequest is null)
                        break;

                    result = await result
                      .NextPageRequest
                      .GetAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex.ToString());
            }

            return _userList;
        }

        static string[] ToStringArray(object arg)
        {
            var collection = arg as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
            if (collection != null)
            {
                return collection
                  .Cast<object>()
                  .Select(x => x.ToString())
                  .ToArray();
            }

            if (arg == null)
            {
                return new string[] { };
            }

            return new string[] { arg.ToString() };
        }
```

To find the latest sign-in date, I'm utilizing **AdditionalData** dictionary results that I obtained from a graph API. But data I'm getting not complete. For the same user sometime, I get results and sometime not and sometimes last login date also get change even if its past date.

Example:
 
I call this method and for X user I got 1st Dec 2022 as last signin date but then next day if I do check again then for same X user it shows 2nd Feb 2023 consider both are past date.

I don't have portal access to verify it so I'm bit confused. Am I doing something wrong in this process?

> Note: I'm using Beta graph API URL

Comment: Hi, if it's not necessary, pls do not use beta version graph api, microsoft won't guarantee beta version can work well and can always work.

Comment: @TinyWang ok will replace beta url

Answer (score 2):

Accourding to your description, I'm afraid `signInActivity` in user property is what you should use to get the last sign in time.

Please note `AuditLog.Read.All permission` and `Azure AD Premium P1/P2 license` is necessary for this property.

By the way, I didn't find a document which explain or mention `AdditionalData` containing user sign in information. So I don't think it can be a good way to get sign in information in this property.

[image]

Comment: actually i do get last signin data from that AdditionalData dictionary property, it is just inconsistent and i dont know why it acting up like that. it just occurs for some exceptional cases..

Comment: yes... it's weird right, so at the beginning I tired to find a document to explain this property but I can't find a `AdditionalData` in [user object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). since there's no document about it, I can think this property doesn't get guaranty from microsoft(because microsoft doesn't say we can get what from this property) so we got a weird behavior from this property might be expected.... let's think there's some retired table column which still be used in some old SDK(you had `.Request()` which is not V5 SDK)

Answer (score 1):

you can get it as json if you do like this.

`await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("id,displayName,companyName,mail,mobilePhone,userType,createdDateTime,Guest,signInActivity").GetAsync();`

Then you should get it in AdditionalData if you have premission